# How to call a global component with out HTML tag in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want a global dialog component which is called only by JavaScript. And never had custom content within it. So I don't want to put any HTML tag like `<my-dialog ref="myDialog"></my-dialog>` in my code. Just call `this.$ref.myDialog.show()`.

I have a HTML tag version. How to instance the component only in JavaScript?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Typically, you would just include the component in your template and programatically show it. Why can you not do that?

Comment: Also, how can you expect to make use of `$refs` without any HTML elements?

Comment: @Phil If I programatically show my component, Where should I put my component's HTML?

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking. Please add some examples to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you neeed to create a JS window with a component inside

here is an example:

```
var componentName = "my-dialog";
var model = {d:1};
var d = document.createElement("div"); // JavaScript Window
document.body.appendChild(d);
d.id = 'win' + componentName;
var app = new Vue({
    render(h, data) {
        return h(componentName, { on: { 'close': this.close }, props: { model: this.model } });
    },
    el: d, data: { wait: false, error: "", after: 0, model },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        close() { 
            this.$destroy();
            $(d).remove(); // remove the window by jQuery


        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign Vue to window.vue.

`window.vue = new Vue({ // options })`

then call it using js. `vue.$ref.myDialog.show()`